# Create wind rose android

Tags: java, android, graph

I would like to create a  wind rose similar to this :

[image: Wind rose]

The goal is to be able to update the green area based on information from a database. 
The green area should take in two degrees and then create the green area between them.

Where could i start looking for a soulution ?

Comment: Trigonometric functions. And some graphics code, of course.

Comment: Use drawing with Canvas over ImageView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As has been mentioned, you'll likely want to implement a custom view.

In particular though, you'll want to divide the rendering into two. The background static image and the foreground dynamic image.

The foreground image could be generated using the Canvas class. It's quite easy to use once you get your head around it. The idea is that you'll be generating a bitmap using the canvas on whcih you draw. See the docs for more details:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html

For the actual rendering, you can use the drawArc method in the Canvas class:

```
public void drawArc (RectF oval, float startAngle, float sweepAngle, boolean useCenter, Paint paint)
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawArc(android.graphics.RectF, float, float, boolean, android.graphics.Paint)

All the best!

Answer (score 2):

Look at how to create a custom view : http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html

And keep in mind that you will have to optimize your drawing code : no object creation and rely as much as possible on java graphics primitives.

Happy coding, that's a very fun android development ahead, but a bit complex for novices.

Oh, and by the way, here you might be interested in using PorterDuff mode for translucency.

Answer (score 2):

I have done such a compass for ios.

Besides custom views, you should be familiar with polar coordinates:

A point then is defined by (r, phi) instead of (x,y). 
You need that all the time, you loop around the rose iterating with phi from 0 to 360, in steps. When you have the drawing coordinates in polar, you have to transform to x,y and draw it.
Further you will need AffineTransformations to scale the rose from a given pixel width, and height to a neutral -1, 1 range. Then drawing is easier.